# Json DeserializeObject throws exception by ios

Tags: c#, ios, json

Exception:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Error getting value from
> 'XXX' on 'xxxxxx'. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object
> reference not set to an instance of an object.

but it works in editor mode

here is my code:

```
Dictionary<string, object> sendMsgDic = new Dictionary<string, object>();
.......
sendMsg = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(sendMsgDic)
```

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce your issue with the code and information you've provided https://dotnetfiddle.net/7NZwqQ. Please post a [mre].

Comment: There is also the generic advice for dealing with Null Reference Exceptions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it